# /usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lecl

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, common-lisp, ecl

I'm trying to compile [Example of a C program embedding ECL with callbacks to C functions.](http://vwood.github.com/embedded-ecl.html) [github](https://gist.github.com/662109). I have installed [ECL (Embeddable Common Lisp)](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/) by cloning the ECL repo with `git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/ecls/ecl ecl` and then `$ make` and `# make install`, and the install seems to ok, at least [ECL Developers' Guide: 2.6 Compiler examples](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/ecldev/Compiler-examples.html) compile fine.

When trying to compile [ecldemo.c](https://gist.github.com/662109) with `gcc ecldemo.c -lecl` I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lecl
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function foo: error: undefined reference to 'ecl_make_integer'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function bar: error: undefined reference to 'ecl_make_integer'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function ecl_call: error: undefined reference to 'ecl_make_simple_base_string'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function ecl_call: error: undefined reference to 'si_string_to_object'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function ecl_call: error: undefined reference to 'si_safe_eval'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function init: error: undefined reference to 'cl_boot'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function init: error: undefined reference to 'cl_shutdown'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function init: error: undefined reference to 'ecl_make_simple_base_string'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function init: error: undefined reference to 'si_string_to_object'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function init: error: undefined reference to 'ecl_def_c_function'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function init: error: undefined reference to 'ecl_make_simple_base_string'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function init: error: undefined reference to 'si_string_to_object'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function init: error: undefined reference to 'ecl_def_c_function'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'ecl_make_simple_base_string'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'si_string_to_object'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'si_safe_eval'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'cl_print'
/tmp/ccRk8Q48.o:ecldemo.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'cl_equal'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I wonder this error row:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lecl
```

It seems to me that `gcc` somehow interprets `-lecl` as a source file, and not as option `-l library` (search the library named `library`) as it should. Leaving a space between `-l` and `ecl` (`gcc ecldemo.c -l ecl`) doesn't help, the output is the same (`cannot find -lecl`).

As `ecl.h` is located in `/usr/local/include/ecl/` and in `ecldemo.c` it's included with `#include "ecl/ecl.h"`, I tried adding a library directory with `-L` option:

`gcc -L /usr/local/include/ecl ecldemo.c -l ecl`

... but to no avail, the same error `usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lecl` persisted.

Any ideas what might cause this error and how could this be fixed?

Comment: -lecl tells gcc to search for a library called libecl. Ld is telling you that it cannot find such library. Do you have in your libraries path? If not such path must be specified with -L. Also note that "ecl.h" is the header file of the library. Having such file does not mean you have the library compiled

Comment: Where is the file `libecl.a` or `libecl.so`?  That's the directory that you need to have for the `-L` option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `-L` option is wrong. You need to tell it where to find the *library*, not where to find the header file. The library is most likely called `libecl.so` or `libecl.a` or something like that.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot, this solved my problem. The correct `gcc` command is  `gcc ecldemo.c -L /usr/local/lib -lecl` .

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify `-lecl` and `-L...` directly, use `ecl-config` instead:

```
gcc `ecl-config --cflags` ecldemo.c -o ecldemo `ecl-config --libs`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://ecls.sourceforge.net/ecldev/Compiler-examples.html

```
;;; Invoking external command: gcc -o "libmyecl.so" -L"/usr/lib/ecl/" "myecl.o" "hello.o"  -Wl,–rpath,/usr/lib/ecl/ -shared   -lecl -lgmp -lgc -ldl -lm
```

I think you need

```
gcc -L/usr/lib/ecl ecldemo.c -lecl
```